# Make phone call over 4G LTE

Tags: gsm

I have used the SIM800L module in the past, but with Ting shutting down their 2G network, I have been looking for alternatives. I have a SIM7000A, but I can't seem to find a microphone or speaker pin. Can this make calls, or will I have to find something else? I am using an Arduino Mega.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SIM7000 doesn't have a microphone or speaker pin.  Instead it provides a PCM interface to connect to an external CODEC chip.

As it says in the [Hardware Design Manual](http://mt-system.ru/sites/default/files/documents/sim7000_hardware_design_v1.05.pdf):

> SIM7000 provides a PCM interface for external codec, which can be used in master mode with short sync and 16 bits linear format.

If you want to use it for phone calls then you will need a module that also incorporates said CODEC chip and all the associated circuitry to connect to a microphone and speaker.